# Centos 6.4 Nodejs external not responding

Tags: linux, node.js, ssh, centos, iptables

I am new to ssh and Centos 6.4 and I want to run nodejs on port 80. But couldn't make it to work external.

When I type `netstat -anp | grep 8080` I can see that my node listening.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7976/node
```

But it is not going external.

I tried to add settings to iptables and result is same again. It is not working.

```
[root@culturalinfluences ~]# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http /* node.js port */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:webcache /* node.js port */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here is my nodejs

```
var port = 8080;
app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0" ,function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Thank you four understand cause I am really new into linux and its iptables system. I am sure people like me will search the same issue and I hope they will find answer from this question.

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

right before the "http" ports you're allowing, so those rules will never be reached. Move the `REJECT all` rule to the bottom of the list instead.

Additionally you may want to use `-n` on the `iptables` command line to make sure the port numbers are right and aren't `80` instead of `8080` for example.